# Linux - Ubuntu - GUI - Remote Mouse and Keyboard from 1 master to 10 slaves

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scripting, shell

Is it possible to replicate mouse and keyboard actions to multiple devices?
e.g. listen on ubuntu 1, then replicate the exact mouse and keyboard actions to ubuntu 2, ubuntu 3, ubuntu 4 and so on.

I have tried with xdotool and ssh but to put it simple, i fail.
e.g.

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh -t -X user@host DISPLAY=:0.0 'bash -a' < ./start.sh

while true
do
    xje=$(xdotool getmouselocation | cut -c 3-5)
    yje=$(xdotool getmouselocation | cut -c 9-12)

    echo "$xje" "$yje"

    xdotool mousemove "$xje" "$yje"
done
```

but maybe you guys have a total different solution? 
because im really stuck!

Comment: Check out the program `cnee` - it can record and play back X11 data (inputs, etc) as well and broadcast it to other machines in real time